# Can't Create C# Azure Function. VS Code

Tags: c#, azure-functions

When I try to create a new Azure Function in VS Code on Mac, I get to choose the programming language. But when I select C#, nothing happens. I can't choose Runtime etc. after this. All other languages are working fine. What could this be?

Comment: Have you installed .NET SDK & Runtime packages of versions 3.1 , 6 - Refer https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0 ?

Comment: I was missing the .NET SDK. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any OS Environment like Windows, Mac OS, Linux - the prerequisites of working with the Azure Functions in Visual Studio Code were:

- Visual Studio Code
- [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4,windows,csharp,portal,bash) (v3 and v4 as v3 is required for .NET 3.1 and 5 and v4 is required for .NET Core 6).
- Azure Tools, Azure Functions, [Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite?tabs=visual-studio-code) extension in VS Code, Azure Storage Emulator for Windows
- Based on language used in Azure Functions, that language extension should be installed like

Example:

- For .NET, .NET 3.1 or 6 SDK and Runtime Packages.
- For Python Azure Functions, Python extension in VS Code and Python Packages.